# Django way for multiple translations for one language or parametrize translations

Tags: python, django, internationalization, translation

I have django app which is backend for javascript application intended for multiple TV devices. Each device has different frontend but I don't think that creating multiple .po files is good idea for this goal, because most of translations are repetitive for these devices.

Is this possible to add additional parameters for translations, for example in my case some function with parameter "device" would be very useful? If not, how to do in Django way?

Comment: translation depends on request you sent, for example when you send request from browser it send header "Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ms;q=0.6,ja;q=0.4", this will decide on which language server has to return output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might get away with using contextual markers: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#contextual-markers and pgettext() though you may have to manually add them to your generated .pot file as the standard extract won't pick up available options if they are parametised.

Answer (score 1):

So you need to translate all versions. At least all keys. If you want to map different keys to same values you can do sth. like this.

```
#: core/models.py:160
msgid "previous"
msgstr "Previous"

#: core/models.py:161 core/models.py:169
msgid "Back"
msgstr "Previous"
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume that you are using Django to create an API, and you consume the API with javascript. You can check the user-agent string from the header and make the appropriate redirect according to the request.

Comment: Yes, Django is my API, but what i need is to store for one language 2 different versions of translations. For example, on one device back button is called "back", on another "previous". And i would like to store all translations in .po files, not inside js clients. That's why i am looking for some method like `ugettextByParam(msgID, deviceID)`